# Decoding media file in chunks with AES 128 in CTR mode

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I have an MP3 file that is encoded and saved locally on the device. In order to play the file I need to decode it in chunks not greater that 515b with AES 128 in CTR mode on the fly. I have an IV for every file in HEX. The file will be played using JWPlayer. I have 2 problems:

**Problem 1:** 
First of all I was trying to decode file as whole just for test purposes.

```
final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CTR/PKCS5Padding";
final byte[] iv = trackIv.getBytes();
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```

The `iv` is hex IV that i `getBytes()` from. I am receiving:

```
com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$1: CTR/SIC mode requires IV no greater than: 16 bytes.
```

My IV is 32 bytes long. Am I doing something wrong?

**Problem 2:**
How should I approach streaming file in chunks? Are there any dedicated classes that would handle that for me? I would be very grateful for any advice that would get me started.

Comment: You should be parsing the hex, not calling `getBytes()` on it. Hex encoding 16 bytes results in...32 bytes!

Comment: `Cipher` is the dedicated class, it has an `update` method which you can feed bytes. No doubt for CTR mode it will immediately return the decrypted data, especially if your chunk is a multiple of the block size (and starting on a block boundary).

Comment: @Kayaman Yes you are right, that solves problem 1.